# Trying to create word count for my webpage, I'm struggling to get it to work. Getting error, pasted below

Tags: javascript, html, string

The error I am getting is index.html:145 Uncaught ReferenceError: countWord is not defined at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeyup

Adding my code snippet below. I am new to all of this still, js to be specific.

````
        <form class="contact-form" onsubmit="sendEmail(); reset(); return false;">
            <h3>Get In Touch!</h3>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name *" required>
            
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email *" required>
            
            <input type="number" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number (Optional)" >
            
            <textarea id="txt" onkeyup="countWord()" onpaste="countWord()" rows="4" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>

            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col">
                    Word Count: <span id="wordCount">0</span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <button id="clearBtn" type="submit">Send message</button>
            
        </form>
    </section>

const textField = document.getElementById("txt");
const wordCount = document.getElementById("wordCount");
const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clearBtn");

function countWord(){
  let text = textField.value;
  text=text.trim();
  let words = text.split(" ");
  wordCount.innerText = words.length;
} ```
````

Comment: Is there really no `<script>` element in your HTML code that encloses your Javascript?

Comment: Its a code snippet. So yes, but not in what i showed you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing  tags. It should look like

```
<script>
function countWord(){
let text = textField.value;
text=text.trim();
let words = text.split(" ");
wordCount.innerText = words.length;
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you so much. That did indeed work :)